# Run a script at startup as a user

Tags: scripting, users, startup

Is there a way to run a script on startup as a user on Debian 7?
My script is

```
screen -dmS name ./script.sh
```

So essentially I want to run a script on startup that would make a screen window and run a script in it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can faff about with an elaborate `sudo` command in `/etc/rc.local`, but the best way is to use the user's `cron` table.  `cron` has some nifty scheduling keywords including `@reboot` which will run the defined script or command when the system is rebooted.

So, as that user, run `crontab -e`, and add this line to the file:

```
@reboot screen -dmS ScreenName /path/to/your/script.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

If you mean when you start the desktop environment then odds are you are using GNOME and this may help you at least get an idea of what to look for.

http://linuxandfriends.com/how-to-add-startup-programs-in-gnome-3/

Ok so from the comments what you want is something to run every time a terminal session is started.

A good place for this is in the user's ~/.profile, or in the /etc/profile if you want it to happen for all users.

Comment: No it's a server actually

Comment: Then what do you mean by screen window? That was suggesting to me a window environment. Did you mean a process that starts when the server boots up?

Comment: Is session the right term then. I want it to make a screen session which I can attach to later if I need to. All this will be done through SSH

Comment: Ok then add it to you .profile in your home it gets sourced every time you open a terminal be it on the box or through ssh.